# How to hide scrollbar without affecting the body width using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to hide the scrollbar without affecting the body width using JavaSCript? Whenever I click a button, the scrollbar gets hidden which is alright, but the body width gets affected. I want the body width remaining the same whether the scroll bar is hidden or not.

Comment: Please paste some code.

Comment: You can use css `margin-right` to do the UI trick. Need you to provide some example codes to work on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the body `overflow: hidden` on clicking the button, you can set `padding-right: 17px` to the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your scrollbar with the following styles without changing affecting on the body:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar
  {
    width: 0;
  }
```

i hope this will work for you.